# My working Docker container has no open ports on Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have a simple NodeJS app I've created an image of.
I can start it and talk to it locally:
`docker run -p 80:80 -it --rm --name test gcr.io/XXX/XXX:0.1`

`$ curl docker
=> Unauthorized`   As expected.

## Kubernetes

*webservice-replication-controller.yml:*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: harvester-webservice
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: harvester-webservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: harvester-webservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: harvester-webservice
        image: gcr.io/XXX/XXX
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

*webservice-service.yml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: harvester-webservice
  labels:
    name: harvester-webservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    -
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: harvester-webservice
```

I've started the cluster as following:

```
$ kubectl create -f webservice-service.yml
$ kubectl create -f webservice-replication-controller.yml

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
harvester-webservice-controller-8qmkl   1/1       Running   0          11m
harvester-webservice-controller-chnky   1/1       Running   0          11m

$ kubectl get services
NAME                   LABELS                                    SELECTOR                    IP(S)            PORT(S)
harvester-webservice   name=harvester-webservice                 name=harvester-webservice   10.NN.NN.NN    80/TCP
                                                                                             104.NN.NN.NN
kubernetes             component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>                      10.NN.NN.NN      443/TCP

$ kubectl get rc
CONTROLLER                        CONTAINER(S)           IMAGE(S)         SELECTOR                   REPLICAS
harvester-webservice-controller   harvester-webservice   gcr.io/XXX/XXX   app=harvester-webservice   2
```

`curl 104.NNN.NNN.NNN` returns:
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

`curl 10.NNN.NNN.NNN` just hangs

The logs are as they should when  I ssh into the container and do a `docker logs` on the Node app.

All tips or suggestions are highly appreaciated!

```
$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME                   ENDPOINTS
harvester-webservice   <none>
kubernetes             104.NN.NN.NN:443
```

Best,
Martin

Comment: You did "curl 104.NN.NN.NN:443" actually, no?

Comment: Sorry for the bad pasting in the original post. I've updated the output from `kubectl services`. I did `curl 104.NN.NN.NN` It's kubernetes that listens on 443.

Comment: What does `kubectl get endpoints` give you @martins?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas, It returnes 'nothing' for harvester-webservice. I've added the output the my post. Any idea why it doesn't have any endpoints?

Comment: OK, so your service doesn't come up since its endpoint isn't there. You need to change the selector in your service to `app: harvester-webservice`.

Comment: Thanks! Good spotted!  Now it returns `10.NN.NN.NN:80,10.NN.NN.NN:80`

Comment: Perfect, now I get the expected answer from `104.NN.NN.NN`. Thanks for helping out @MichaelHausenblas :-)

Comment: OK, so it works now? I'll answer with this one and would appreciate if you upvote/mark as the correct answer then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94439/discussion-between-michael-hausenblas-and-martins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the selector in `webservice-service.yml` to `app: harvester-webservice` so that it matches the label in `webservice-replication-controller.yml`.

See also [Services](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html) in Kubernetes.